# Can't extract table from a Select query Cursor in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table from which i have to get rows which have KEY_DATE = dat.

I am then saving these rows as objects and returning a list of those objects.

The problem is that if I have 4 entries in my table, then instead of getting all 4 rows, I'm getting the last row 4 times.

Here is my code...

```
while(!l.isEmpty())
    {
        hd = l.get(0);
        l.remove(0);
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Log.w("myapp",hd._name+hd._price+hd._qty);

        map.put("item", hd._name);
        map.put("price", Double.toString(hd._price));
        map.put("qty", Integer.toString(hd._qty));
        map.put("total", Double.toString(hd._price*hd._qty));
        mylist.add(n++,map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, R.layout.details_item_list, new String[] {"item", "price", "qty" , "total"}, new int[] {R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3, R.id.col4});
    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

The items are being retrived , but my listview is showing the last item only mutliplied by the number of items in my sql table . Am i using the map.put() and add() function in loop correctly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you only have one instance of `HistoryDetails`, which you add 4 times inside your List, modifying it on each iteration. You need to put `hd = new HistoryDetails();` inside your loop, like

```
hd = new HistoryDetails();

hd._qty = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
hd._name = c.getString(1);
hd._price = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2));

l.add(hd);
```

Comment: try logging `id` to make sure it's different on each iteration: `Log.d("getMyHistoryOnDate", "id is: " + id)`;

Comment: yes , it worked , but the problem now is in my listview showing these items . check my new edit

Comment: got it , forgot to include new hashmap inside the loop .

Answer (score 2):

```
    .....
    Cursor cursor = .......   
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        hd = new HistoryDetails();  // IMPORTANT !!!!

        hd._qty = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
        hd._name = cursor.getString(1);
        hd._price = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2));

        l.add(hd);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    .......
```

Comment: You use Cursor c; (is undefined !!!!!) and Cursor cursor (defined !!!) in your code. Remove Cursor c;

Comment: `Cursor c` is defined inside `do {} while ()` loop

Comment: cursor c is defined in do while loop , using it to extract data from another table .

Comment: I am getting GC_Concurrent freed in logcat , with your code , which means there is some memory leak